# What does the Scala interpreter (REPL) print exactly (demonstration with Map and HashMap)?

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections, hashmap, read-eval-print-loop

I have the following two Maps in the REPL in Scala:

Case 1

```
scala> var a1=Map("a" -> "b", "c" -> "d", "e" -> "f", "g" -> "h") 
a1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a -> b, c -> d, e -> f, g -> h)

scala> var a2=Map("a" -> "b","c" -> "d","e" -> "f","g" -> "h","i" -> "j")
a2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(e -> f, a -> b, i -> j, g -> h, c -> d)
```

Both of the above examples print the same text in the REPL:

```
...
scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = ...
```

But the following two examples show different output text:

Case 2

```
scala> a1.getClass.getName
res10: String = scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map4

scala> a2.getClass.getName
res11: String = scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap
```

Why are the text outputs (`scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map4` and `scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap`) in the REPL different? What does the output text mean exactly? I know that `Map` with more than four elements uses `HashMap` instead of `Map`, but why are the output texts the same in case 1 (for variable `a1` and `a2`), and different in case 2?

Comment: For performance reasons, `Map.apply` (which is called implicitly) returns a different implementation of the `Map` trait, depending of how many key-value pairs are stored.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look in the [reference documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-immutable-collection-classes.html#hash-tries), you can read that a [HashTrieMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/HashMap$$HashTrieMap.html) is the default implementation of an immutable map.

However,  Scala has a further optimization for immutable sets and maps that contain less than five elements. Sets and maps with one to four elements are stored as single objects that just contain the elements (or key/value pairs in the case of a map) as fields - that is why you see the class [Map4](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map$.html#Map4[K,+V]extendsAbstractMap[K,V]withMap[K,V]withSerializable).

Comment: Maps don't typically guarentee iteration order. If you need an immutable map that does then [ListMap](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap.html) is what you want.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I understand the performance reason but why are not the output texts different in case 1? Why does the case 1 contain the following text `scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]` and not `...scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map4...` or `...scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap...`?

Comment: `scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]` is the type of the variable `a1`, `Map4` is the type of the value held by `a1`